# What tools exist that help me reference topics within a .CHM from a WinForms app?

Tags: .net, winforms, chm

I have inherited both an existing WinForms app and an existing .CHM file, created using [Dr. Explain](http://www.drexplain.com/). I need to reference different topics within the CHM from different parts of my WinForms app, but I don't know what topics, if any, are defined within the CHM. Is there a tool that lists all existing topics that I can reference using the `System.Windows.Form.Help` class? If there are no topics or I need to add a new one (let's say I want to add a topic named "TwainScanning" to existing content within the .CHM), is there a tool for that? I could ask the author to add some, but she is not very technical and I need to explain my request very carefully. Exactly what do I ask her to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The topics are roughly equal to the html files.

See 
[How to check if a subfile exists in a chm file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2004156/how-to-check-if-a-subfile-exists-in-a-chm-file)

how to get a list of the html files in the archive.

Aside from this, there is a TOC and an INDEX that also have topics. (and these can refer to anchors too). They are usually encoded in the chm file as .hhc and .hhk files, which you can extract from the CHM using an extracter.

Modifying a file without the tool it was made with (the exact chm compiler project files etc) is hard.

Answer (score 0):

The [HelpProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.helpprovider(VS.71).aspx) will allow you to access specific parts of the help file. Not sure about your other questions though.

Comment: Downvotes without comment aren't particularly useful. Please let me know where I went wrong and how I can improve :-)

Comment: @flipdoubt: Sorry if it seemed like I was directing that at you. Someone did but I don't assume to know who.